# Javadoc link for vararg methods

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Suppose I have this:

```
/**
 * Single-word method.
 */
private void say(String word) {
    System.out.println("Single word: " + word);
}

/**
 * Multiple-word method.
 */
private void say(String... words) {
    System.out.print("Multiple words: ");
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.print(word);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

/**
 * {@link #say(String...)}
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void testJavadoc() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    say("hello");
    say("world");
    say("hello", "world");
}
```

If I run this, I get:

```
Single word: hello
Single word: world
Multiple words: helloworld
```

This proves that there is nothing wrong in defining a method with `String` and an overload with `String...`.

When I mouse-over `testJavadoc()`, this is the Javadoc I see:

```
void testJavadoc()

@SuppressWarnings(value={"unused"})

say(String)
```

Clicking on `say(String)` brings me to the Javadoc for the first method without vararg.

If I remove `say(String)` method, then the Javadoc works fine.

I'm using eclipse neon 3 (4.6.3). Is this supposed to be the correct behavior?

Comment: `{@link #say(String[])}` works perfectly in the popup javadoc window, but it does not convey that there is a vararg parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might be a bug in Eclipse, as you are correct in that it should reference the vararg method (I don't have Eclipse so I am unable to test).

Testing in IntelliJ, I can see the expected reference.

More-so, if you go ahead and actually generate the JavaDoc, you should be able to see the correct output.

[image: Generated JavaDoc]

Comment: Thanks, at least I can conclude it's the problem with Eclipse now.